# Django REST Framework form data no submit with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post data using postman with x-www-form-urlencoded.
When I send request an eroor is occuring saying-

```
{
    "detail": "Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter."
}
```

post data is contained `{'name': 'hello'}`

this is my view:

```
serializer = Web2TypeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

NOTE: Post data not containg any file.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error, I believe your request needs the `Content-type: application/json` header. You're trying to send `json` rather than form data. (Or, at least, you have configured it to expect and parse json as first preference; check your DRF settings in `settings.py` if this wasn't intentional and you truly meant to submit a json object as form data).

The equivalent request in curl is:

```
curl https://example.com/my/endpoint/ 
  -X POST\ 
  -H "Content-type: application/json"\
  -d '{"name":"hello"}'
```

Comment: Check WHAT though?